How do I run Grok-1 on MS Azure after importing from GitHub?
I have just got the Microsoft Azure and I would like to use its speed and cloud-based computing to run
Grok-1 by X ai.
I imported the Repository from GitHub, and now I have all the files on my project tab on Devops.
Where I am stuck is on how to run the code and how to download necessary files.
The image below shows where I am:
Grok import into Azure
How do I run the code and feed it data to analyze and modify?

According to the readme, the pipeline should first download the weights and then proceed to test the code.
However, when attempting to run the pipeline using Microsoft-hosted agents, it fails with the error: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device.
Microsoft-hosted agents come with a 2-core CPU, 7 GB of RAM, and 14 GB of SSD disk space. The readme notes that

Due to the large size of the model (314B parameters), a machine with enough GPU memory is required to test the model with the example code.

Therefore, the disk space provided by Microsoft-hosted agents is not enough for running the test. It is necessary to set up a self-hosted agent with more disk space (more than 314B parameters). Instructions for configuring a self-hosted agent can be found here.
After setting up, you can use the following azure-pipelines.yml to execute the pipeline on your self-hosted agent.
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: default   #your self-hosted agent pool name.

steps:
- script: |
    pip install huggingface_hub[hf_transfer]
    huggingface-cli download xai-org/grok-1 --repo-type model --include ckpt-0/* --local-dir checkpoints --local-dir-use-symlinks False
  displayName: 'Downloading the weights'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      pip install -r requirements.txt
      python run.py
  displayName: 'test the code'

